# Handling Large MQ objects in Java

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I am working on reading large MQ messages in Java and processing + writing the contents of MQ message to a file.

The code I am writing is multi-threaded and can process multiple messages in parallel.

The writing application writes (PUT) large MQ message to the queue using Segmentation+Grouping.

Now, while reading below steps take place.

1. Set appropriate values for MQGetMessageOptions.

   ```
   MQGetMessageOptions getGroupMsgOptions = new MQGetMessageOptions();
   getGroupMsgOptions.options =  MQC.MQGMO_LOGICAL_ORDER | MQC.MQGMO_SYNCPOINT 
   | MQC.MQGMO_ALL_MSGS_AVAILABLE | MQC.MQGMO_COMPLETE_MSG;
   ```
2. Initializing MQQueue  -  serverFileQueue and MQMessage - reqMessage.
3. Invoking get method for MQQueue by passing reqMessage and getGroupMsgOptions.

   ```
   serverFileQueue.get(reqMessage, getGroupMsgOptions);
   ```
4. Checking the MQ message flags in a while loop to identify last segment of last message in group.
5. Write the message contents to a file using BufferedOutputStream.

My question is, if the MQ message is too large, should the code be getting *java.lang.OutOfMemoryError*?

I am trying to understand if step 3 `serverFileQueue.get(...)` would load entire MQ Message in memory?

OR only segments would be loaded hence no need to worry about  *java.lang.OutOfMemoryError*?

Answer (score 3):

The message will be retrieved in segments,so you need not worry about the OutofMemory error.But each segment should be a separate MQGET Call and you have to use the GroupStatus and SegmentStatus properties of MQGMO for retrieving all the segments of the message.

Answer (score 2):

First, MQ will not throw java.lang.OutOfMemoryError.  As 'subbaraoc' says, the code will perform an MQGET for each message segment and it is up to your code to re-assemble everything.

Secondly, if you have 75 '100MB' segments then the JVM may throw java.lang.OutOfMemoryError because JVM does not have enough memory for what you are doing.

Third, why are you re-inventing the wheel.  The is a FREE open source project, written in Java, that does exactly what you are doing.  It is called [Universal File Mover](http://www.capitalware.com/ufm_overview.html).  You can download the source code to see how the code handles message segmentation.

Answer (score 2):

As you include the option MQGMO_COMPLETE_MSG, the QM will assemble the logical message for your application, so yes, your get will return the whole message.

As mentioned previously, it is possible to get the segment messages and assemble the logical message in your application, but you need to change the code for that. Some more explanation:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q026390_.htm

And by the way grouping and segmentation is two very different things. Grouping is used to specify order of separate logical messages, while segmentation allows one large logical message to be transferred as multiple smaller segment messages. Segmentation does not require or imply grouping.
So I think, the option MQGMO_ALL_MSGS_AVAILABLE doesn't make much sense in your case, and should use MQGMO_ALL_SEGMENTS_AVAILABLE instead.